# When can you use this in a constructor?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, constructor

I am going through the [solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/contracts.html#creating-contracts) and I have seen that:

```
    // Functions can
    // be accessed directly or through `this.f`,
    // but the latter provides an external view
    // to the function. Especially in the constructor,
    // you should not access functions externally,
    // because the function does not exist yet.
```

At what circumstances should you use this in a constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
constructor() {
  foo();
}

function foo() public {
...
```

but you cannot do this:

```
constructor() {
  this.foo(); // external call to non-existant function
}

function foo() external {
```

`foo()` is indeed available as an external function from functions but the constructor doesn't "write" the code until the end, so `foo()` does not exist until the constructor is finished.

Hope it helps.